# What does 星辰大海 mean?

Tags: meaning, word

As far as I know, 星辰is used to mean time, and even when used literally, it has nothing to do with 大海, or it makes no sense, especially when put in the context of 我们的目标是星辰大海, which could be heard in mainstream media like Radio China.
So what does it really mean?

Comment: If you just figuring the connection, imaging travel in the middle of the ocean like "Life Of Pi", all you can see is stars and ocean. As the answer descibres below, it is originated from a Japanese scientific novel, to indicate an ambitious target.

Answer (score 1):

星辰 means stars, Milky Way. 大海 is great ocean.
Both are huge, boundless.
It's used to decribe we have a very ambitious target.

Answer (score 1):

辰 - 清早(dawn). It also means collectively the star, moon, and sun (日月星辰).

星辰 - (Countless) stars in the early morning sky. It is interpreted through 會意 (huìyì) - largeness (浩瀚星辰). Also, "largeness" is a characteristic of 大海 (大海無邊).

So, the sentence "我们的目标是星辰大海" means "Our goal is so deep and large like the universe and oceans that have no limits". In another similar way: "我们的目标是(深)遠(鉅)大無邊的的", a suggestive slogan.

Answer (score 1):

无边无际 像星河一样，一般形容人和宽广的胸襟，或者是因为某件事情体会到自己的渺小

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the phase could have older historical background written by a dude known as Heinrich Heine, but it was popularised more so by a Japanese anime known as **[Legend of the Galactic Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Galactic_Heroes)** (It is basically a Japanese rendition of the Chinese classic 'Three kingdoms', but in space, nonetheless it is something that is bingeworth imo).

The phase is often used to describe someone or a group of people with 'serious' ambitions.

Or people just uses it for memes as a references at times.